# Do I need a neutral wire when connecting a 240V device?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

So this is still not very clear to me: I am trying to get 240V to an appliance that does not need a plug (direct wiring), I won't need a neutral wire, is this right? In fact there is nowhere to connect it on the appliance, right? I just need the two hot wires wired to the L1 and L2 lines and it will work. Additionally, I can wire the ground to the ground line, for safety (not doing this would be crazy), but no current would go through this during normal operation, right? I might be completely wrong here, just trying to understand.

I started from this thread: [Why Do 240V Circuits Not Require Neutral?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/why-do-240v-circuits-not-require-neutral/68127#68127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a 240v 30amp welder wired in the way you described.  Hot, Hot, Ground.

Be sure to use the correct 2 pole breaker.

Comment: Great, it finally worked. I also was not using a two-pole breaker, so dumb. My AC is now humming.

Answer (score 3):

Depends partly on the device. Some electric ranges/cooktops/driers have electronic controls which run on 120V even though they're controlling 240V; they get that 120V by connecting between one leg of the 240V supply and neutral. In that case, obviously, without neutral those controls don't run.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. If you're installing a 240 volt load, there's no need for the grounded (neutral) conductor.  As you suggest, you will need a grounding conductor though.