NEMA 14-30 generator output to European 220V
I've got a deep well pump variable frequency drive/inverter that can accept DC solar or AC inputs. It's powering a 1.5 hp three phase pump/motor that takes 200V at 6.8A (58 Hz).
(this is the inverter):
https://solarsovereign.com/products/growatt-2-2kw-3hp-solar-pump-inverter-l-water-pump-inverter-grid-assisted-spi-2200tl2-hv
It's operating via solar as expected, but I need to run it from my generator sometimes (cloudy days etc.). The inverter has European style AC input (three wires -- line, neutral, ground). I have a Nema 14-30 cord coming out of the generator (10000W). I cut of the end and capped off the neutral (white) wire. Red is going to line, black to neutral, ground to ground.
The AC output is not what I'm expecting. The frequency ramps up to 50 Hz and stops. Output voltage stops at 155V, amperage at 4.2A. Pump doesn't start obviously.
What am I missing here? It this European "appliance" getting confused by the AC input wiring?

The inverter is expecting AC220-240V. What are you supplying via the generator?

I would expect a 10KW generator to be strong enough to provide 240V to the inverter, but yes, should definately check that.

See this post https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/69071/nema-10-30-to-european-220v?rq=1

The generator is supplying 240V (verified with a meter across red and black wires.

The inverter takes neutral off the 14-50 plug?  That's weird.  That's a "consult with the factory" sort of question, not an "Ask Dr. Internet" sort of question. I assumed you obeyed 110.3 and followed instructions and labeling, implying "read them", and that was no help.
